# Is this the right way? How to get Hex value into a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, tcp, hex

I need following `char packet[] = {0x00,0x14};` to send over a TCP/IP, this is the only way I got it to work. With that char I would send the number 20, another possible example would be `char packet[] = {0x4e,0x20};` that would be 20000. I am Starting to think that I am approaching this completely wrong.

With this code I can print the Hex value of an Int out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num, temp, i = 1, j,k=1, r;
    char hex[50] = {};
    char paket[7] = {'0','x'};
    cout << "Input?";
    cin >> num;
    temp = num;
    while (temp != 0) {
        r = temp % 16;
        if (r < 10)
            hex[i++] = r + 48;
        else
            hex[i++] = r + 55;
        temp = temp / 16;
    }
    cout << i << endl;
    cout << "\nHex = ";
    for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        cout << hex[j];
        switch (k)
        {
        case 1:
            paket[2] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        case 2:
            paket[3] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        case 3:
            paket[4] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        case 4:
            paket[5] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        }
        k++;
        
    }
    cout << endl << paket;
    return 0;
```

This part is how I am trying to get the format I need, but sadly it's not working.

```
switch (k)
        {
        case 1:
            paket[2] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        case 2:
            paket[3] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        case 3:
            paket[4] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        case 4:
            paket[5] = { hex[j] };
            break;
        }
        k++;
```

Comment: Please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the ASCII value for `'0'` then use the actual character instead.

Comment: As for your problem, remember that decimal, hexadecimal or even octal are just different ways to present the underlying *binary* value. If you want a string with hexadecimal digits, why not use `snprintf`, as in `snprint, paket, sizeof paket, "0x%04x", num)`? Or considering that you're programming in C++ use some kind of stream (e.g. `std::ostringstream`).

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex value'. Everything in the computer is binary. Hex is just a notation used by humans. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to convert a number than can be expressed in 16-bits into an array of 2 bytes using network byte order as you imply.

```
int num = 20000; // or any number for that matter

char packet[2];
packet[0] = (num & 0xff00)>>8;  // 0x4E
packet[1] = (num & 0x00ff);     // 0x20
```

Done.

Alternatively, most network programming uses [memcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) to byte-pack integers into byte arrays:

```
uint16_t num = 20000;
char packet[2];
memcpy(packet, &num, 2);
```

The only problem is that on Little Endian platforms, such as all Intel chips, the above code will write `{0x20, 0x4E}` into the array. The bytes will be in the wrong order.  There's a helper function that swaps those bytes out called [htons](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons). The header files to import htons and similar functions vary between OS platform, but is available everywhere.

```
uint16_t num = 20000;
char packet[2];
num = htons(num);       // swaps bytes on little endian, no-op on big-endian
memcpy(packet, &num, 2);
```

Comment: memcpy is exactly what I have been searching for the last week. I knew about htons and that is actually what I have been finding all along while trying to solve the problem I never found memcpy.

Comment: This works now but I have two new problems. First sending works every second time, have to find out why might open a new question for that or edit an old one.  Second problem where you might be able to help. I am getting an Input from a Window ```GetWindowText(hWndEdit, buffer, 1024);````buffer is an ```wchar_t``` I convert that to an int using ```int Input = _wtoi(buffer);``` is there a way to use int with memcpy or is there a way to convert int to uint16_t?

Comment: Yes memcpy works with int, just got it to work. Now i have to find out why it only works every second time.